# How to speed up Jekyll/Octopress generation?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress

I'm using Octopress as my blog engine. It's perfect. But if there are many posts, for example 400+ posts, the speed of generation is soooo slow.

So, is there any way to speed up Jekyll/Octopress generation?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd love to know this, too! But I already know what `isolate` and `integrate` does, so hopefully someone will post an answer how to generate only the new stuff with the `generate` command!

Comment: I use Jekyll instead of Octopress, but have come up with a process that helps speed up editing and design changes. The idea is to work on a sub set of files that can generate quickly and only generate the full set just before deployment. The same approach might work for Octopress. You can see my full description of the process here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14674402/102401

Answer (score 3):

Obviously if you are just working on one post, there is no need to wait for the entire site to generate. What you are looking for is the rake isolate[partial_post_name] task.
Using `rake isolate`, you can “isolate” only that post you are working on and move all the others to the `source/_stash` folder. The `partial_post_name` parameter is just some words in the file name for the post. For example, if I want to isolate the post from the earlier example, I would use

```
rake isolate[plain-english]
```

This will move all the other posts to `source/_stash` and only keep the `2011-09-29-just-type-the-title-of-the-post-here-in-plain-english.markdown` post in `source/_posts`. You can also do this while you are running `rake preview`. It will just detect a massive change and only regenerate that one post from then on.

by [@Pavan Podila](https://twitter.com/pavanpodila)
More Info: [Tips for Speeding Up Octopress Site Generation](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/09/tips-for-speeding-up-octopress-site-generation/)

2013.01.08 update:
[Hexo](http://zespia.tw/hexo/)--A fast, simple & powerful blog framework, powered by Node.js.
Features:Incredibly fast - generate static files in a glance

**2013.6.20 update:**
**[gor](https://github.com/wendal/gor)** -- A static websites and blog generator engine written in Go
gor has following awesome benefits: **1. Speed -- Less than 1 second when compiling all my near 200 blogs on wendal.net** 2. Simple -- Only one single executable file generated after compiling, no other dependence

Comment: I think this is only a partially answer on the question. For sure, nothing is wrong what you said, but your answer does not explain how to compile the complete site, without compiling the stuff which is already compiled.
I'd love to know this, too!

Comment: @musicmatze hi,you can try to use [hexo](http://zespia.tw/hexo/),A fast, simple & powerful blog framework, powered by Node.js.Incredibly fast - generate static files in a glance.

Comment: @musicmatze try gor -- A static websites and blog generator engine written in Go.https://github.com/wendal/gor

Answer (score 1):

Install Ruby GSL

```
gem install gsl
```

You should notice a speed increase.

Comment: Can you explain why?  What does jekyll use from gsl?

Comment: I agree, can you explain? Also this gem install fails.

Comment: Jekyll's "related posts" uses latent semantic indexing, provided by Classifier::LSI. To do so, it uses vector analysis features, which can be accelerated by (a Ruby wrapper of) GSL, the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/).  If GSL isn't available, a pure-Ruby implementation is used, but it's exceptionally slow for big sites, and using GSL improves performance ~10x.

Comment: _should_ notice? Do you have reasons why this works? Do I just use `jekyll build` after without extra flags?

Answer (score 1):

hexo powered by Node.js. I am using it, much faster than Octopress. And it provides a simple way to migrate your articles to hexo very easily.

Comment: hexo is indeed very fast. I switched from DocPad to hexo because of speed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176094/show-only-partial-blog-post-in-docpad-with-read-more-link

Comment: hexo is great, but migration is not for me. Some markdown are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate only one post while you are writing it using

```
rake isolate[your-post]
```

and then

```
rake integrate
```

to go back to normal.

To fully answer your question, you **can't generate only one post**. You can see Octopress' [Issue #395](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/395) on that subject, which explains that this is due to a limitation on Jekyll's side.

Answer (score 0):

Reached this post with the same problem, but then did not quite like the idea of rake isolate. Also the inbuilt task does not integrate with the _drafts workflow.
So what I ended up using is to create a custom config.yml with the _posts folder excluded (using exclude) and have only the drafts folder built. You can pass in a different config file as command line parameter to jekyll. I just used this when actively writing new posts and while publish use the same old approach (which still does take some time). This approach builds only the draft post and I am good with that.

```
jekyll build --watch --drafts --config _previewconfig.yml
```

For those interested in the complete worklow take a look [here](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/optimizing-octopress-workflow-for-new-posts/)

Answer (score 0):

If your blog has a lot of images (and other static assets that do not change between builds), it is worthwhile to exclude them from Jekyll's build process, and instead manually update them as needed.

For whatever reason, `Jekyll build` is not intelligent when it comes to handling such assets. It will delete everything in the `public` folder, and re-copy the contents in `source` **every** time you build. This is wasteful if the assets haven't changed. This can be avoided by using a tool such as Robocopy (Windows) or Rsync (Linux) that is able to update **only** what has changed.

To tell Jekyll to ignore a folder, add the following to `_config.yml`:

```
exclude:     # exclude from build
  - folderPath
keep-files:  # do not delete/empty copy in `public`
  - folderPath
```

Then elsewhere, use whatever tool you want to update the folder.

---

For more things you can try, see [this post](https://mademistakes.com/articles/using-jekyll-2017/).