# How to generate only new posts in octopress?

Tags: ruby, rake, octopress

I'm using octopress to generate both my website and blog. If I write a new post, I always have to do

```
rake generate
```

or

```
rake gen_deploy
```

But I don't want to generate *everything* all the time. It takes up to 2,5 min on my machine, and that's maybe too long, also because I have to do this if I fix a typo or so.

How to generate only the new post and depending pages (E.G. if I have a new post, the blog index page has also to be regenerated of course)?

Comment: The question has been asked and partially answered already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217394/how-to-speed-up-jekyll-octopress-generation).

Comment: As I commented in the question you linked and as you said, this question is only partially answered. I still don't know how to `generate` only the new stuff!

Answer (score 3):

You can generate only one post while you are writing it using

```
rake isolate[your-post]
```

and then

```
rake integrate
```

to go back to normal.

To fully answer your question, you **can't generate only one post**. You can see Octopress' [Issue #395](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/395) on that subject, which explains that this is due to a limitation on Jekyll's side.