# Getting a post excerpt in DocPad

Tags: docpad

This is what I'm currently using to "grab" my posts: https://gist.github.com/Greduan/5977871

And then I do a for loop `.toJSON()` etc.

How can I make this grab an excerpt of the post and not all of the content? Cause I can just use `@content` but that'll output the entire post.

How can I make it have for example an excerpt with something like 500 characters then "..." and then a "Continue reading..." link or something along these lines.

I was thinking maybe using something like this:

```
@content.slice(0,500)
```

Or something like that. Would that work?

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: The difficulty with a straight slice is that you may be slicing html. For instance, what happens if you slice inside of a code block or script tag, etc. You can do this quite easily be manually specifying the excerpt you're after, would that be sufficient?

Comment: @balupton How do you mean? Something like putting a string for it to search for? Once it finds it it slices just before it, or something along those lines?

Comment: The manual example is like adding `excerpt: "blah blah blah"` to your document's meta data. With the [text plugin](http://docpad.org/p/text) you can still accomplish rendering with the meta data.

Comment: @balupton Ah I see. It seems like a good and simple solution, but it can be a little annoying, what if I decide to change some of the text for example... Then I need to change it on two places. Not a big deal but not ideal, is there another method perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show only partial blog post in Docpad, with "Read More" link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176094/show-only-partial-blog-post-in-docpad-with-read-more-link)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answers here: [Show only partial blog post in Docpad, with "Read More" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176094/show-only-partial-blog-post-in-docpad-with-read-more-link) - they all involve some work, but the top one would probably do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Right now I decided to not use this approach, but when I do I'll accept your answer if it's relevant. :)